<Base> href does not work for javascript in Edge Browser for local files
I have some local html files which have relative paths for style sheets and javascript:
<link href="/css/rendering.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/task.js"></script>

With a <base> href set, the css works, but the script does not, if I set a full path on the script it works (and it's the correct path if I was using <base>).
The css and javascript are hosted on a web server, the html files are held on a local drive.
<base href="http://example.com/myservice/public" >

Resources behind /public (the css and javascript) do not require any Authentication.
I don't generate the html files, but I'm looking for the easiest option to make them work locally so the inclusion of the <base> seemed like the logical solution instead of having to edit the src.
Any ideas why this would not work?
UPDATE:
By setting a full path, the css and javascript loaded fine.
By setting a <base> with href css worked, javascript didn't.
Further digging into the console shows that the javascript is being blocked: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"
So the issue comes into play when the <base> is set, but not when full paths are used. Now that is odd.

Just as @Peter B said, adding a / to the href of <base> and removing the starting / of <link> and <script> should be the best practice.
<link href="css/rendering.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/task.js"></script>
<base href="http://example.com/myservice/public/" >

If it is still not working after that, you need to check your Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings of your server.
Additionally, you've mentioned the easiest option. Then you should simply try launching Edge with command line --allow-file-access-from-files. Remember to close all Microsoft Edge instances first from task manager.

You need to use relative URLs, so not starting with a "/":
<link href="css/rendering.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/task.js"></script>

I tried it, this small change makes local CSS and Script files work in Edge + Chrome + Firefox, even without <base href> present.

Ok, I see the idea, but for me it didn't work, the css and javascript files are hosted on a server, so I need the base tag for the local files to know where to find these files.  Removing the preceding slash didn't fix it for the javascript.

That there is also a server in play is an important detail that you should mention in the question itself. Please [edit] the question to include it. And while you are at it, also include the exact content of your <base href> element.

Try if adding a / to the href value makes it work, so this: <base href="http://example.com/myservice/public/">



<link href="css/rendering.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="script/task.js"></script>



If you’re working with local HTML files and facing issues with relative paths, it’s because browsers treat relative paths differently when loading files directly from the file system (e.g., file:// path) compared to loading from a server...
so once try this one :
